# map eigen::matrixXf to array

Tags: c++, eigen

In eigen, i [need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003692/mapping-array-back-to-an-existing-eigen-matrix) to place a MatrixXf unto an existing array.
Now, this works:

```
    MatrixXf Um=FFMatBas(xi,CalcMetod);
    Map<VectorXf>Uv(Um.data(),ppp);
    Map<VectorXf>(Q,ppp)=Uv;
```

but it seems a bit convoluted (Q is an existing array of length ppp). 
Can we do the last two lines in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MatrixXf Um=FFMatBas(xi,CalcMetod);
Map<VectorXf>(Q,ppp)=Map<VectorXf>Uv(Um.data(),ppp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Q is big enough to contain the matrix, you can also write this as:

```
MatrixXf Um = FFMatBas(xi,CalcMetod);
Map<MatrixXf>(Q, Um.rows(), Um.cols()) = Um;
```